# Hibernate merge adds instance to database in contrast to update

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

Hibernate session.update() is deprecated and the recommended function to use is merge().
Update() only updates the database if an entry with the primary key exists and throws an exception if not. Merge() adds a new instance if the entry is not in the database.

Is there a similar method to update() which only updates the database if the entry exists and throws an exception otherwise?